# Identify contents from UIScrollView

Tags: ios

I have two UIScrollView in a page having 26 UIImageView in each which contain same type of images but in jumbled condition.In the middle of the page there is a frame .How can I check the similarity when two same images come inside the frame from both the UIScrollView.

Comment: That's not a good solution, you should use a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`. It would perform better, and it's easier to retrieve the current page/offset/item.

Comment: A quick solution: Put tag to your images. Check which one image is shown. Check if they have the same tag.

Comment: simply use two `UIPickerView` and just compare the selected index of it